# Retrieve integers from a text file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I would like to retrieve some numbers from a text file using Windows PowerShell. Assume that I have a text file `values.txt` that looks like this (I can modify it as I want):

```
foo=100
bar=-3
foobar=-15
asdf=-4
```

I would like to add a variable to my PowerShell script called `$bar` that is equal to the number `-3`, as the text file says it should be. How do I do this?

Comment: It is expected that you would at least try _something_. If your keys are unique I would look into `ConvertFrom-StringData`

Comment: @Matt and others: My question was clear, concise, sufficiently distinct from other questions (in my view as a beginner, at least), and phrased in a general way that could help those who came here via a search engine query. Before I asked this, I did a bit of research on SE and elsewhere, but did not find enough helpful information, so I thought I would ask here. And I'm glad that I did because some nice person out there has now solved this problem.

Comment: @Matt: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2784835

Comment: If you are going to quote that you might note that you didnt really follow the suggestions there. This reads like a code writing request. Yes, your question is easy to follow but proving a little effort does not hurt. I am glad you got an answer.

Comment: @Matt: I assumed that this post I shared was sarcastic. I think this site can have a culture that's very unfriendly to beginners, and I think you should consider whether your comment is making the site a better place or if it is contributing to this toxic culture. I doubt that people who find something useful in the answers here after finding this question on Google care much whether or not I "tried something," which makes this all a real shame because receiving downvotes and negative comments discourage people and prevent them from making a useful contribution on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$file = "C:\test.txt"

foreach($line in (Get-Content $file)) {
    $a = $line.Split("=")
    New-Variable -Name $a[0] -Value $a[1]
}

Write-Output ""
Write-Output "Variable Check ::"

Write-Output "foo = $foo"
Write-Output "bar = $bar"
Write-Output "foobar = $foobar"
Write-Output "asdf = $asdf"
```

You can also put the name/value in different variables if you don't want to use an array, just change the for loop:

```
$a,$b = $line.Split("=")
New-Variable -Name $a -Value $b
```

Using Matts suggestion of `ConvertFrom-StringData` :

```
$line =  $line | ConvertFrom-StringData
New-Variable -name $line.Keys -Value $line.Values
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Note: The input file looks like part of an `*.ini` file; for more full-featured support of such files, consider a third-party module such as [`PSIni`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/).</sup>

As [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt) suggests in a comment on the question, **[`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata)** sounds like the right tool:

```
# Read the key-value pairs stored in file file.txt into [hashtable] $ht
PS> ($ht = Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath file.txt | ConvertFrom-StringData)

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                               
----                           -----                                                                                                                                               
foo                            100                                                                                                                                                 
bar                            -3                                                                                                                                                  
foobar                         -15                                                                                                                                                 
asdf                           -4                                                                                                                                                  

# Access a specific value:
PS> $ht.foo  # or: $ht['foo']
100
```

Note:

- `ConvertFrom-StringData` returns a *hashtable* rather than creating *individual variables*:

  - As shown above, you must access the `foo` input line's value as `$ht.foo` (or `$ht['foo']`) rather than `$foo`, for instance.
  - To ensure that only a *single* hashtable is created, `Get-Content -Raw` (PSv3+) must be used to pass the entire input file as a *single string*.
- `ConvertFrom-StringData` only ever creates `[string]` values, so if the input values should be treated as *numbers*, for instance, *manual conversion* is required:

  ```
  # .Clone() is needed to support enumeration and modification in the same loop.
  foreach($key in $ht.Keys.Clone()) { $ht.$key = [int] $ht.$key }
  ```
- Generally, there are more subtleties to consider, such as `\` rather than `` ` `` serving as the escape character and quotes getting retained as literals - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata).